# Индикатор прихода письма на неактивной вкладке в браузере

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, браузер

Часто замечал что когда откроешь несколько вкладок с различными сайтами одна из которых к примеру с открытым почтовым ящиком на hotmail, появляется красная или любого другого цвета точка в области favicon сигнализирующая о приходе нового письма или писем когда вкладка не активна, когда же вкладка становится активной эта точка тут же пропадает.
Вопрос: подскажите пожалуйста хотя бы чем это предоставляется.
Предположения: есть предположение что это как то связанно с push уведомлениями и с service workers, помогите пожалуйста подтвердить догадку или хотя бы как реализуется данная функция по верхам.

Comment: простой сменой favicon-а? )

Comment: практически первое попавшееся  в гугле https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-display-update-notifications-in-the-browser-tab--cms-23458 в конце есть ссылка на js библиотеку. Push-ведомления и сервис-воркеры отвечают за получение увдомлений от сервера. К самому отображению всяких плюшек на вкладках они не относятся никак.

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо комментатору за ответ)

Чтобы никто случайно не пропустил продублирую коммент от teran:

практически первое попавшееся в гугле webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/… в конце есть ссылка на js библиотеку. Push-ведомления и сервис-воркеры отвечают за получение увдомлений от сервера. К самому отображению всяких плюшек на вкладках они не относятся никак. –
teran